# Using variable as part of another variable name

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a variable as part of another variable's name.

For example, I have some variables in a `CONFIG_` scope.

```
echo $CONFIG_systema_value > "testconfig"
echo $CONFIG_systemb_value > "testconfig2"
```

and then I have a "deciding" variable like `WANTEDSYSTEM`

```
echo $WANTEDSYSTEM > "systema"
```

I need to be able to "dynamically" switch the config depending on the wantedsystem variable.

My initial attempts I tried something like this `echo $CONFIG_$WANTEDSYSTEM_value` which I would like to have output `testconfig` as if I was asking it to `echo $CONFIG_systema_value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `${!name}` syntax to indirectly reference a variable, like this:

```
CONFIG_systema_value=foo
CONFIG_systemb_value=bar
WANTEDSYSTEM=systema

target_var_name="CONFIG_${WANTEDSYSTEM}_value"
echo ${!target_var_name}
```

(Note that this is bash-specific syntax, but it sounds like that's what you're looking for.)

Comment: Isn't it any trick with `eval` to make it in one line with `echo`?

Comment: Sure, you could write something like `eval echo "\$CONFIG_${WANTEDSYSTEM}_value"`, but I avoid `eval` when possible because if you're not careful what you pass to it it can have unintended side effects.